# Error when using \usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,autocite=plain,sorting=none]{biblatex}

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, errors, compiling, biber

I am trying to add bibliography to my code by typing:

```
    \usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,autocite=plain,sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

Here is how my .tex file looks like:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    %\pagenumbering{gobble}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage[english]{babel} 
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
    \usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
    \usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
    \setcellgapes{1pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
    %to use portrait mode for the table
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    %to use item inside table
    \newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    %linked ref and cite
    \usepackage{footnote}
    %colorfy the footnote
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{red}{\arabic{footnote}}}
    \makesavenoteenv{tabular}
    \makesavenoteenv{table}

    %%bibliography
    \usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,autocite=plain,sorting=none]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{ref.bib}
    %subcaption for figures
    \usepackage{subcaption}

    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }

    %rename the list of tables
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}





    \title{Search for a new scalar decaying to two
    beyond-the-Standard-Model light bosons and then
    on to a four-lepton final state with 140 $fb^{-1}$ at $\sqrt{s}$ = 13 TeV}
    \date{}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%        
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables

    %\chapter{Introduction}
    %\label{sec:Intro}
    %\input{chapters/introduction}
    %
    %
    %\chapter{Theoritical context}
    %\label{sec:theory}
    %\input{chapters/Theory}

    \chapter{LHC and ATLAS detector}
    \label{sec:LHC}
    \input{chapters/LHC_and_ATLAS_detector}
    %
    %\chapter{Physics objects reconstruction and identification}
    %\label{sec:Phyobj}
    %\input{chapters/PhysObj}
    %\chapter{$ET_{miss}$ performance in $Z \rightarrow ll$ topology}
    %\label{sec:ETmiss}
    %\input{chapters/QTreport}


    %change the bibliography name to References
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

and this is how my .bib looks like:

```
  @techreport{Etmiss:note,
  title         = "{$E_{\text{T}}^{\text{miss}}$ performance in the ATLAS
                   detector using 2015-2016 LHC p-p collisions}",
  institution   = "CERN",
  collaboration = "ATLAS Collaboration",
  address       = "Geneva",
  reportNumber  = "ATLAS-CONF-2018-023",
  month         = "Jun",
  year          = "2018",
  url           = "https://cds.cern.ch/record/2625233",
  }
  @article{Aad:2017,
  title={Performance of algorithms that reconstruct missing transverse momentum       
  in $\sqrt{\text{s}}$ = 8 TeV proton--proton collisions in the ATLAS detector},
  author={Aad, Georges and Abbott, B and Abdallah, J and Abeloos, B and Aben, R and Abolins, M and AbouZeid, OS and Abramowicz, H and Abreu, H and Abreu, R and others},
  journal={The European Physical Journal C},      
  volume={77},
  number={4},
  pages={1--46},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Springer},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1140%2Fepjc%2Fs10052-017-4780-2}
  }
  @unpublished{cern:complex,
  author        = "Vanden Broeck, Renilde",
  title         = "{THE CERN ACCELERATOR COMPLEX.}",
  month         = "Sep",
  year          = "2019",
  url           = "https://cds.cern.ch/record/2693837",
  }
  @article{Aad:2008,
  title         = "{The ATLAS Experiment at the CERN Large Hadron Collider}",
  journal       = "JINST",
  collaboration = "ATLAS Collaboration",
  volume        = "3",
  pages         = "S08003. 437 p",
  year          = "2008",
  url           = "https://cds.cern.ch/record/1129811",
  note          = "Also published by CERN Geneva in 2010",
  doi           = "10.1088/1748-0221/3/08/S08003",
  }
  @article{Aad:TRT,
  title         = "{The ATLAS Inner Detector Trigger performance in $pp$
                   collisions at 13 TeV during LHC Run 2.}",
  journal       = "Eur. Phys. J. C",
  collaboration = "ATLAS Collaboration",
  archivePrefix = "arXiv",
  eprint        = "2107.02485",
  reportNumber  = "CERN-EP-2021-076",
  volume        = "82",
  pages         = "206. 79 p",
  month         = "Jul",
  year          = "2021",
  url           = "https://cds.cern.ch/record/2774961",
  doi           = "10.1140/epjc/s10052-021-09920-0",
  }
  @article{HC:FCAL,
  author        = "Archambault, J P and Artamonov, A and Cadabeschi, M and
                   Epshteyn, V and Galt, C and Gillberg, D and Gorbounov, P
                   and Heelan, L and Khakzad, M and Khovanskiy, V and Krieger,
                   P and Loch, P and McCarthy, T G and Oakham, F G and Orr, R
                   S and Rutherfoord, J and Savine, A and Schram, M and
                   Shatalov, P and Shaver, L and Shupe, M and Strickland, V
                   and Thompson, P and Tsukerman, I",
  title         = "{Performance of the ATLAS liquid argon forward calorimeter
                   in beam tests}",
  journal       = "JINST",
  volume        = "8",
  pages         = "P05006",
  year          = "2013",
  url           = "https://cds.cern.ch/record/1984169",
  doi           = "10.1088/1748-0221/8/05/P05006",
  }
  @article{HC:HEC,
  doi = {10.1016/j.nuclphysbps.2004.10.087},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1016%2Fj.nuclphysbps.2004.10.087},
  year = 2006,
  month = {jan},
  publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
  volume = {150},
  pages = {102--105},
  author = {T. Barillari},
  title = {The {ATLAS} liquid argon hadronic end-cap calorimeter: construction and selected beam test results},
  journal = {Nuclear Physics B - Proceedings Supplements}      
  }
  @unpublished{MagSyst:2020,
  author        = "Rodriguez Vera, Ana Maria and Antunes Pequenao, Joao",
  title         = "{ATLAS Detector Magnet System}",
  month         = "May",
  year          = "2021",
  url           = "https://cds.cern.ch/record/2770604",
  note          = "General Photo",
  }
  @INPROCEEDINGS {30824,
  author={ATLAS Experiment},
  doi={},
  title={ATLAS Fact Sheets},
  year={2021},
  url="https://atlas.cern/Resources/Fact-sheets",

  }
```

but i get this error:

```
    thesis.tex:66: File ended while scanning use of \strng. \begin{document}
```

please tell me if i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Don't dump simply your preamble into your question. Clean it up and make a small, complete example that we can test.

Comment: `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`  are you really using latin 1? Certainly the code as posted to this site always uses UTF-8 so will need this line deleting

Comment: When I run your full code but _without_ the line `\input{chapters/LHC_and_ATLAS_detector}` (that refers to a file you didn't provide) and instead put `\nocite{*}` in that chapter to show the references, then the document runs without errors (there are three warnings but they are unrelated). So either the problem is in the chapter, or there is something wrong with the encoding of your `.tex` file - but the first cause (problem in the chapter) seems much more likely.

Comment: As others have commented, the code shown so far is unfortunately not enough for us to investigate your issue properly. For one it does not allow us to reproduce the error (I just checked: I removed all references to files I don't have, then `\nocite{*}`'d all work, this resulted in a working bibliography). But it is also too verbose and contains lot of unrelated stuff.

Comment: You may want to try deleting your auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`) and recompiled from scratch. The issue is quite probably related to the `.bbl` file. But without a useful example it is hard to say more.